# Generating a fibonacci pyramid

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

How can I generate the following pyramid (where the first and second rows are imposed beforehand)?

```
          1 
       1  4  1 
    1  5  6  5  1  
 1  6 12 16 12  6  1
```

This is what I've tried so far, but it didn't work:

```
def main():
    first_row = [1]  # given in the question
    second_row = [1, 4, 1]  # given in the question
    sum = 0
    n = int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
    list_of_rows = list()
    list_of_rows.append(first_row)
    list_of_rows.append(second_row)
    for i in range(2, n):
        list_of_rows.append([])
        for j in range(0, 2*i+1):  # each row is 2 digits bigger than the previous

            list_of_rows[i].append(sum)
    print(list_of_rows)
```

Comment: You're not changing sum

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a variation of what would be a fibonacci pyramid, where the second row should be a `[1,1]` instead.

A nice and concise way to add rows to the sequence would be to convolve the preceding row with `[1,1,1]`. You can use [`np.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) for that:

```
n = 4
l = [[None]]* n
l[0] = [1]
l[1] = [1,4,1]

for i in range(2,n):
    l[i] = list(np.convolve(l[i-1], [1,1,1]))

print(l)
[[1], [1, 4, 1], [1, 5, 6, 5, 1], [1, 6, 12, 16, 12, 6, 1]]
```

---

For the standart Fibonacci pyramid, a solution would be:

```
n = 10
l = [[None]]* n
l[0] = [1]
l[1] = [1,1]

for i in range(2,n):
    l[i] = list(np.convolve(l[i-1], [1,1]))

print(l)
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1], [1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1], [1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1], [1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1], [1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]]
```